# JSON_MODIFY is adding extra "\" in front of "/"

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert a value in my existing JSON by using inbuilt JSON functions in SQL Server.

Existing JSON:

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      "type": "_api",
      "content": {
        "acId": "sometext/567890"
      }
    }
  ]
}


SET @JSONData = JSON_MODIFY(@JSONData,'$.array[0].content.uId ', 'sometext/1234/locations/1234')
```

But the resulted value inserted in JSON is coming as shown below.

I need it to come as
`sometext/1234/locations/1234` but it got added as `sometext\/1234\/locations\/1234`.

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      "type": "_api",
      "content": {
        "acId": "sometext/567890",
        "uId": "sometext\/1234\/locations\/1234"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: There's no difference. It's an escape, which while unnecessary, is not necessarily bad practice. It's simply escaping *anything* that could be seen as a control character, with the \.

Comment: If you *want* to fix it, try `SET @JSONData = REPLACE(JSON_MODIFY(@JSONData,'$.array[0].content.uId ', 'sometext/1234/locations/1234'), "\\/", "/")`

Comment: [`STRING_ESCAPE()` explicitly mentions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-escape-transact-sql) that for JSON it will try to escape solidus (forward slash), though it doesn't mention that `JSON_MODIFY()` uses `STRING_ESCAPE()` under the covers. As a workaround, you could consider using a different character and change your consumer to understand, say, a pipe or semi-colon, or some other separator that doesn't exist in the data. Or you could simply brute force `REPLACE()` after the modification (though that has the danger of replacing other valid character sequences).

Comment: Thanks people for the help, 
I have corrected it , replacement of "\\/" should be '\/' and Json_modify should be converted back to Varchar
SET @JSONData = REPLACE(CAST(JSON_MODIFY(@JSONData,'$.array[0].content.uId ', 'sometext/1234/locations/1234') AS nvarchar(max)) , '\/', '/')

Comment: SET @JSONData = JSON_MODIFY(@JSONData,'$.array[0].content.uId ', JSON_QUERY('sometext/1234/locations/1234'));

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate your JSON_MODIFY with replace function to the incorrect characters:

```
SET @JSONData = REPLACE(JSON_MODIFY(@JSONData,'$.array[0].content.uId', 'sometext/1234/locations/1234'), '\/', '/')
```

Comment: You should use `"\/"` instead of `"\\/"`

Comment: Used single quotes '\/','/' instead of double quotes in REPLACE function